# Error loading page (on js of a bootstrap template)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, loading

since i added to the store template de left sidebar with js there´s no option to load any link of the same page; there is a problem that show on screen: Error loading page.

I don´t know so much of js so i can´t resolve it by myself; I think it is something easy but i can´t find it.

Would you help me please?

Thanks

https://server417290.vservers.es/bootstrap/store.html

Comment: Can you provide some code so that others can examine it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.